# ClientDependency 2nd level not resolving

Tags: javascript, asp.net, partial-views, client-dependency

I have a setup like this :

Layout_Admin

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Admin</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Html.RenderCssHere()
@Html.RenderJsHere()
</head>
<body> ... </body>
```

Then the first partial page that is loaded on Category.cshtml

```
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin > Category";
    Layout = "~/Views/Admin/_Layout_Admin.cshtml";
    Html.RequiresJs("~/scripts/jsTree3/jstree.js");
    Html.RequiresJs("~/scripts/jsTree3/jstreegrid.js");
    Html.RequiresCss("~/content/jsTree/themes/default/style.css");
  }
```

These scripts get rendered flawlessly without a trouble. Now Category.cshtml loads another partial called _CreateCategory.cshtml that has following head

```
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc
@model MyProject.Data.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = null;
    Html.RequiresJs("~/scripts/plupload/plupload.dev.js");
    Html.RequiresJs("~/scripts/plupload/moxie.js");

}
```

This last set of client dependencies are not being rendered at all. _CreateCategory.cshtml is loaded via a controller action that is called in js.

```
$("#btn_addCategory").on("click", function(e) {
                $("#categoryDetails").load("CreateCategoryView");
```

So question is how to get the scripts defined in this partial rendered. If i include these scripts in Category.cshtml they get rendered but _CreateCategory.cshtml still shows them as undefined.

I think this is because js is calling the controller action instead of an @Html.Action in the razor page. but doing that is not an option here for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the loaded html in console.log?

Comment: yes i did, the scripts are not being rendered.

Comment: CreateCategoryView is this action render the view correctly? Can you check it by hitting it from URL?

Comment: The view is rendered properly, just scripts aren't there. its simple controller action that just returns the partial view.

Comment: Yeah I understood your question, just wanted to make sure that without js load if you paste the action url in your browser does it still render the same?